# How does the probability distribution of Y different from the original X?

Tags: statistics

let $X\sim N(0,1)$. Suppose for constant $c>0$, define $Y$ as $Y=X$ if $|X|\leq c$ and $Y=-X$ if $|X|>c$. I'm trying to find the probability distribution of $Y$, but it seems to me that the probability distribution of $Y$ is the same as $X$. Are they different?

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. $$E(e^{sY})=\int_{|x|>c}e^{sx-x^2/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\int_{|x|<c}e^{-sx-x^2/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ Now do the change of variable $x'=-x$ in the last integral to obtain finally $E(e^{sY})=E(e^{sX}).$

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get the covariance of $X,Y$? I'm trying to find $E(XY)$ but I don't know how to do the integrationl.

Comment: $E(XY)=-1+2\int_{|x|<c}x^2e^{-x^2/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Then express the integral in terms of the function $\Phi(c)=\int_{-\infty}^ce^{-x^2/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ by an integration by parts.